# Mfile execution time

Tags: matlab

how can I compare the execution time of two different methods simultaneously in MatLab?
actually I used "tic-toc" but I'm not sure if I did it in a correct way or not.
this is how I do it:

```
clc;
clear all;
A=rand(10);
B=rand(50;
tID1=tic;
y1=function1(A,B);
t1=toc(tID1);
tID2=tic;
y2=function2(A,B);
t2=toc(tID2);
```

Comment: Looks fine. See also [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function)

Comment: As @LuisMendo suggests, you should really look into `timeit`. There are a lot of subtleties in timing MATLAB code, which `tic` and `toc` do not deal with. `timeit` handles things properly. In recent versions, `timeit` is built in to MATLAB, otherwise download by following Luis' link.

Answer (score 2):

Use matlab's built in [profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) for better understanding of your code's run-time bottlenecks.

```
profile clear; %// reset profiler's history
profile on;    % start recording
y1 = function1( A, B ); % your code here...
y2 = function2( A, B );
profile off;   % stop recording
profile viewer; % visualize the results.
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks @Shai . I loved it. O_o

Comment: But @Shai, I have a problem here with this codes. my 1st and 2end functions are so alike each other but here in the part in which it indicates the lines which need more time to execute, it talks about different lines; for example, I have s=1,2,...,8 in both but it just indicates that "s=5;" elapse a high amount of time in "fun1".To make it clear, why just fun1? we have this code in fun2 too;and why just s=5? we have s=1;...s=8; and it's not also acceptable for me that a simple initialization plays a critical role in execution time. sorry if I don't explain good; I hardly talk english... O_o

Comment: @ilegna It is hard to understand the problem from your comment. If the code is not too long you may capture the results of `profile` in a screen shot and post this comment as a new question.

Comment: it's tooooooooooooo long :(.
I will fined a way to explain ...
thanks any way @Shai ... . I really liked it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is correct. You don't even need to define `tID1` and `tID2` the way you are using it. So you can also do:

```
clc;
clear all;
A=rand(10);
B=rand(50;
tic;
y1=function1(A,B);
t1=toc;
tic;
y2=function2(A,B);
t2=toc;
```